# JSF panelGroup background color set from database value

Tags: css, jsf

I have a set of records in a panel grid where I want to set the background color from the hidden value fetched from ebean. I want to assign the hidden field value as background color instead of yellow.

```
   <h:panelGroup style="background:Yellow;" >                               
   <h:outputText value="#{item.rackTagCode}"/>
     <h:inputHidden value="#{colorEBean.colorCode}" id="hiddenColor" />
   </h:panelGroup>
```

Can anyone please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "#{....}-value access for style-attributes, too.

Just define a value which holds the style information in your backing bean in your backing bean and access it via

`<h:panelGroup style="#{colorEBean.bgColorValue}" >`

where bgColorValue is a string variable which holds the color value, constructed from the database value. For example,

```
String bgColorValue = "background: yellow"
```

will set the background to yellow. Append other color values instead of yellow to get other background colors.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.as i did
<h:panelGroup style='background:"#{colorEBean.colorCode}"'>
as i checked code view style class looks like this and i dont see the color,is anything wrong with my code?
<span style="background:&quot;#FFF00&quot;">

Comment: Try style="background: #{colorEBean.colorCode}"

Comment: yes,after i remove the quotation marks,it's working.thank you very much